# Make Osx Text shortcut works when using Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: macos

On Yosemite it's possible to define text shortcuts in **System Preferences > Keyboard > Text** But they don't work when I'm on Microsoft Remote Desktop app, is there a way to make them work on it?

Answer (score 1):

In an RDP session, everything you type is sent to the host computer, not interpreted by your local machine. You'd need to define the shortcuts you want to use on the Windows box you're accessing to use them.